# Saving data to a file in opencv

Tags: opencv

I need to save the area of connected components as a text file and i have written a code as below, but i dont know where i am going wrong. Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

```
imagefet=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(lab),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
CvMemStorage* contour_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contours;
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0, 2);
cvFindContours(lab, contour_storage, &contours, sizeof (CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
cvZero(imagefet);

FILE *file=fopen("mytxt.txt","W");
for( int ncount=1; contours != NULL; contours = contours->h_next, ncount++)
 {
    CvScalar color =  CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
    cvDrawContours( imagefet, contours, color, CV_RGB(255,255,255), -1, CV_FILLED, 8 ,cvPoint(0,0));        
    int area = abs(cvContourArea(contours, CV_WHOLE_SEQ));      
    fprintf(file,"%d",area);        
  }
fclose(file);
```

thnx

Comment: Well, you haven't said *what* is wrong yet.

Comment: i need to print like   "1. area = , 2. area= 3. area=" in text file. how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't been very specific about the error.

If your file is not opening, I'd suggest you use a lower-case `w` as the mode flag.  I've never seen an upper-case one used, and I don't know if that's allowed.

If your file is full of numbers with no spaces, it's because you do not write out any space.  Try adding a newline `\n` to the `fprintf` call:

```
fprintf(file,"%d\n",area);
```

In that respect, you should really use text mode to create the file `"wt"` instead of `"w"`.

The other thing you should do is *test* whether the file opened successfully by checking whether `file` is NULL after the `fopen` call.

Comment: i solved that and it is printing in the text. Now i need to print like "1. area = , 2. area= 3. area=" in text file. how can i do this?

Comment: `fprintf( file, "%d. area = %d\n", ncount, area );`